# Azure Logic App Data Lake Connector Authentication Issue. How to fix?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-logic-apps

I have created a Logic app work flow on azure to pull the data from Azure DB and upload the same to Data Lake. For this I am using SQL and DataLake Connectors. While uploading the data to DL I am facing Authentication Issue. I did all the steps for Service-to-service authentication with Data Lake Store using Azure Active Directory.

Note: I am using my personnel Azure Account for this.

**Azure DataLake Connector:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Azure DataLake file Upload Rest API Return this type of Error. I was Fix it.

This error is came for url redirect issue and Parameter missing.

```
https://<yourstorename>.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/mytempdir/list.txt?op=CREATE
```

HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect to

```
https://<yourstorename>.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/mytempdir/list.txt?op=CREATE&write=true
```

if you are and file into first URL using putasync .it's redirect to second URL it's not accepted for rest url's and it's throw the unauthorized issue.

You can Directly give the second URL it's working fine. because it's having required params and without redirect. So, It's Upload and give success response.

I was checked in Rest API File Upload. and Authorization header with Bearer Scheme and Token in Required for this Required.I think already you passing Token only url query string is missing I think.

I Think it's helpful for you. Replay me.